# Is there an "if -then - else " statement in XPath?

Tags: xpath, if-statement

It seems with all the rich amount of function in xpath that you could do an "if" . However , my engine keeps insisting "there is no such function" , and I hardly find any documentation on the web (I found some dubious sources , but the syntax they had didn't work)

I need to remove ':' from the end of a string (if exist), so I wanted to do this:

```
if (fn:ends-with(//div [@id='head']/text(),': '))
            then (fn:substring-before(//div [@id='head']/text(),': ') )
            else (//div [@id='head']/text())
```

Any advice?

Comment: Is there more context to the problem?  XPath is usually used to query information, not as a manipulation tool.  Manipulation is usually left to something like an XSL template or a higher level language

Comment: I find the w3schools tutorials easy to work with.  You might start there.  http://www.w3schools.com/Xpath/

Comment: @James: This is actually a query. Don't let the if-then-else syntax fool you - it's technically a "conditional expression" and not an "if statement" - more akin to the ternary conditional operator in many programming languages.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833225/xslt-1-0-idiom-for-ternary-if

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do it in XPath 1.0:

```
concat(
  substring($s1, 1, number($condition)      * string-length($s1)),
  substring($s2, 1, number(not($condition)) * string-length($s2))
)
```

This relies on the concatenation of two mutually exclusive strings, the first one being empty if the condition is false (`0 * string-length(...)`), the second one being empty if the condition is true. This is called *"Becker's method"*, attributed to [Oliver Becker](http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/%7Eobecker/XSLT/) *(original link is now dead, [the web archive has a copy](http://web.archive.org/web/20160725130810/http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/%7Eobecker/XSLT/))*.

In your case:

```
concat(
  substring(
    substring-before(//div[@id='head']/text(), ': '),
    1, 
    number(
      ends-with(//div[@id='head']/text(), ': ')
    )
    * string-length(substring-before(//div [@id='head']/text(), ': '))
  ),
  substring(
    //div[@id='head']/text(), 
    1, 
    number(not(
      ends-with(//div[@id='head']/text(), ': ')
    ))
    * string-length(//div[@id='head']/text())
  )
)
```

Though I would try to get rid of all the `"//"` before.

Also, there is the possibility that `//div[@id='head']` returns more than one node.
Just be aware of that — using `//div[@id='head'][1]` is more defensive.

Comment: I'll probably won't use this (I'll just upgrade the xpath engine) but this is a great trick and a great tip :)

Comment: With numeric expressions (it you don't need to select any string) it's simpler since you can do X * number(condition) + Y * number(condition) etc., where number(condition) gives you 0 for false and 1 for true ("Boolean True is converted to 1; Boolean False is converted to 0." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa926043.aspx)

Comment: maybe a +1 is needed in those expressions, I had to add such at:

  <xsl:template match="i:item">
    <xsl:param name="selection"/>

    <xsl:variable name="selected" select="@id=$selection"/>
      
    <li class="menuItem" id="{substring('current', number(not($selected)) * (string-length('current')+1))}">
...

Comment: the becker method. I was looking for the `?` operator of c#.

Comment: @LuckyLikey Well, we can't all get what we want, can we? There is a nicer way to do it in XPath 2.0+.

Comment: @Tomalak Be sure, im glad I found this solution. Thanks for the hint with XPath 2.0+

Comment: @Tomalak The link is broken, here's another link to a page discussing the method: http://blog.alessio.marchetti.name/post/2011/02/12/the-Oliver-Becker-s-XPath-method

Answer (score 27):

The official language specification for [XPath 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/) on W3.org details that the language *does indeed support if statements*. See [Section 3.8 Conditional Expressions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-conditionals), in particular. Along with the syntax format and explanation, it gives the following example:

```
if ($widget1/unit-cost < $widget2/unit-cost) 
  then $widget1
  else $widget2
```

This would suggest that you *shouldn't have brackets surrounding your expressions* (otherwise the syntax looks correct). I'm not wholly confident, but it's surely worth a try. So you'll want to change your query to look like this:

```
if (fn:ends-with(//div [@id='head']/text(),': '))
  then fn:substring-before(//div [@id='head']/text(),': ')
  else //div [@id='head']/text()
```

I do strongly suspect this may fix it however, as the fact that your XPath engine seems to be trying to interpret `if` as a function, where it is in fact a special construct of the language.

Finally, to point out the obvious, insure that your XPath engine does in fact support XPath 2.0 (as opposed to an earlier version)! I don't believe conditional expressions are part of previous versions of XPath.

Comment: I don't think it suggests you *shouldn't* use parentheses, only that you don't *need* to use them. If it's complaining about "no such function," then I suspect he's not using XPath 2. The spec requires parentheses around the conditional.

Comment: @Rob: It's quite possible, but then I do state that it may not necessarily be the fix. Always worth following the example if you're trying to get something working, however. :)

Comment: But yeah, I missed the brackets around the condition somehow. Fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

How about using fn:replace(string,pattern,replace) instead?

XPATH is very often used in XSLTs and if you are in that situation and does not have XPATH 2.0 you could use:

```
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="condition1">
      condition1-statements
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="condition2">
      condition2-statements
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      otherwise-statements
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 4):

according to pkarat's, law you can achieve conditional XPath in version 1.0.

For your case, follow the concept:

```
concat(substring-before(your-xpath[contains(.,':')],':'),your-xpath[not(contains(.,':'))])
```

This will definitely work. See how it works. Give two inputs

```
praba:
karan
```

For 1st input: it contains `:` so condition true, string before `:`  will be the output, say `praba` is your output. 2nd condition will be false so no problems.

For 2nd input: it does not contain `:` so condition fails, coming to 2nd condition the string doesn't contain `:` so condition true... therefore output `karan` will be thrown.

Finally your output would be `praba`,`karan`.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would use XSLT to transform the XML and remove the trailing colons.  For example, suppose I have this input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
    <Paragraph>This paragraph ends in a period.</Paragraph>
    <Paragraph>This one ends in a colon:</Paragraph>
    <Paragraph>This one has a : in the middle.</Paragraph>
</Document>
```

If I wanted to strip out trailing colons in my paragraphs, I would use this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    version="2.0">
    <!-- identity -->
    <xsl:template match="/|@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- strip out colons at the end of paragraphs -->
    <xsl:template match="Paragraph">
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- if it ends with a : -->
            <xsl:when test="fn:ends-with(.,':')">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <!-- copy everything but the last character -->
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, string-length(.)-1)"></xsl:value-of>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the previous answers were no option for me so i researched for a while and found this solution:

http://blog.alessio.marchetti.name/post/2011/02/12/the-Oliver-Becker-s-XPath-method

I use it to output text if a certain Node exists. 4 is the length of the text foo. So i guess a more elegant solution would be the use of a variable.

```
substring('foo',number(not(normalize-space(/elements/the/element/)))*4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat simpler XPath 1.0 solution, adapted from Tomalek's (posted here) and Dimitre's ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977309/nested-conditional-if-else-statements-in-xpath)):

```
concat(substring($s1, 1 div number($cond)), substring($s2, 1 div number(not($cond))))
```

Note: I found an explicit number() was required to convert the bool to an int otherwise some XPath evaluators threw a type mismatch error. Depending on how strict your XPath processor is type-matching you may not need it.