# XSLT 1.0 Idiom for ternary if?

Tags: xslt, xpath, boolean, ternary

This Java program makes use of a Ternary if, to map booleans to output strings: (a "*" for true, an empty string for false).

```
public class ternary {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean flags[]={true,false,true};
    for (boolean f : flags) {
      System.out.println(f?"*":"");
    }
  }
}
```

So the output is *, [empty], *.

I have an input XML document, something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="change.xsl"?>
<root>
  <change flag="true"/>
  <change flag="false"/>
  <change flag="true"/>
</root>
```

And I have the following XSLT template which maps true to '*' and false to '' (it works):

```
<xsl:template match="change">
  <xsl:variable name="flag" select="translate(substring(@flag,1,1),'tf','*')"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$flag"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Is there is more concise version of this ?

a) Can I automatically get a value of boolean true|false directly from the string 'true|false' ?
b) Is there an (xpath?) construct to map the boolean true|false to '*', '' ?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971067/is-there-an-if-then-else-statement-in-xpath

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> a) Can I automatically get a value of boolean true|false directly from
>   the string 'true|false' ?
>
> b) Is there an (xpath?) construct to map the boolean true|false to
>   '*', '' ?

**This is actually an XPath question**.

**I. XPath 1.0**

There are more than one XPath expressions the evaluation of which produces the wanted result:

```
substring('*', 2 -(@flag = 'true'))
```

This also answers b) -- notice that the *strings* `'true'` and `'false'` aren't boolean values! The only two boolean values are `true()` and `false()` and they are not strings.

In the above expression we use the fact that in XPath 1.0 if a boolean is in a context where a number is needed, it is automatically converted to number. By definition:

`number(true())` is  `1`

and

`number(false())` is  `0`

Thus the second argument of the call to `substring()` above:

```
2 - (@flag = 'true')
```

is evaluated as `1` when `@flag = 'true'` and to `2` otherwise.

**A more general XPath 1.0 expression that produces the string `$s1` if `$val` is `"x"` and produces the string `$s2` if `$val` is `"y"`** :

```
concat(substring($s1, 1 div ($val = "x")),
       substring($s2, 1 div ($val = "y"))
      )
```

This produces the string `$s1` when `$val = "x"`, the string `$s2` when `$val = "y"`, and the empty string -- if none of these two conditions holds.

The above XPath 1.0 expression can be generalized to produce N different string results `$s1`, `$2`, ..., `$sN` exactly when `$val` is one of the values `$v1`, `$v2`, ..., `$vN`  because  the function `concat()` can have any number of arguments.

---

**II. XPath 2.0 (XSLT 2.0)**

```
'*'[current()/@flag = 'true']
```

And more generally, given 2*N atomic values `$s1`, `$s2`, ... `$sN` and `$v1`, `$v2`, ..., `$vN`, such that all `$vi` values are different, the result of evaluating this XPath 2.0 expression:

```
 ($s1, $s2, ..., $sN)[index-of(($v1, $v2, ..., $vN), $v)]
```

is `$sK` exactly when `$v eq $vK`.

Comment: @monojohnny: Good question. The reason for '2-x' is to get 1 or 2. XPaths indexing is 1-based , not 0-based.

Comment: ah yes, I forgot XSL strings are 1-bound ! Cheers ! makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You could utilise simple pattern matching in templates for this.

```
<xsl:template match="change[@flag = 'true']">

<xsl:template match="change">
```

So, the first one matches **true** entries, and the other one matches all other cases (which in your cases is just **false**

So, given the following stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="change[@flag = 'true']">
      <xsl:text>*&#13;</xsl:text>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="change">
      <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
*

*
```