# Nested conditional if else statements in xpath

Tags: xpath, conditional-statements, if-statement, xpath-2.0

I have this XML:

```
<property id="1011">
    <leasehold>No</leasehold>
    <freehold>Yes</freehold>
    <propertyTypes>
        <propertyType>RESIDENTIAL</propertyType>
    </propertyTypes>
</property>
```

and I want to create an xpath statement that is same as the following nested if-else pseudocode block.

```
if( propertyTypes/propertyType == 'RESIDENTIAL') {
    if( leasehold == 'Yes' ){
        return 'Rent'
    } else
        return 'Buy'
    }
} else {
    if( leasehold == 'Yes' ){
        return 'Leasehold'
    } else
        return 'Freehold'
    }
}
```

I've seen something about Becker's method but I couldn't really follow it. XPath isn't my strong point really.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**I. In XPath 2.0 one simply translates this to**:

```
   if(/*/propertyTypes/propertyType = 'RESIDENTIAL')
    then
     (if(/*/leasehold='Yes')
       then 'Rent'
       else 'Buy'
     )
     else
       if(/*/leasehold='Yes')
         then 'Leasehold'
         else 'Freehold'
```

**XSLT 2.0 - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence select=
   "if(/*/propertyTypes/propertyType = 'RESIDENTIAL')
   then
     (if(/*/leasehold='Yes')
       then 'Rent'
       else 'Buy'
     )
     else
       if(/*/leasehold='Yes')
         then 'Leasehold'
         else 'Freehold'
   "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<property id="1011">
    <leasehold>No</leasehold>
    <freehold>Yes</freehold>
    <propertyTypes>
        <propertyType>RESIDENTIAL</propertyType>
    </propertyTypes>
</property>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output:**

```
Buy
```

---

**II. XPath 1.0 solution**

In XPath 1.0 there isn't an `if` operator.

A conditional statement can still be implemented with a single XPath 1.0 expression, but this is more tricky and the expression may not be too readable and understandable.

Here is a generic way (first proposed by Jeni Tennison) to produce `$stringA` when a condition `$cond` is `true()` and otherwise produce `$stringB`:

```
concat(substring($stringA, 1 div $cond), substring($stringB, 1 div not($cond)))
```

**One of the main achivements of this formula is that it works for strings of any length and no lengths need to be specified**.

**Explanation**:

Here we use the fact that by definition:

```
number(true()) = 1
```

and

```
number(false()) = 0
```

and that

```
1 div 0 = Infinity
```

So, if `$cond` is `false`, the first argument of `concat()` above is:

```
 substring($stringA, Infinity)
```

and this is the empty string, because `$stringA`  has a finite length.

On the other side, if `$cond` is `true()` then the first argument of `concat()` above is:

```
sibstring($stringA, 1)
```

that is just `$stringA`.

So, depending on the value of `$cond` only one of the two arguments of `concat()` above is a nonempty string (respectively `$stringA` or `$stringB`).

Applying this generic formula to the specific question, we can translate the first half of the big conditional expression into:

```
concat(
           substring('rent',
                      1 div boolean(/*[leasehold='Yes'
                                     and
                                       propertyTypes/propertyType = 'RESIDENTIAL'
                                      ]
                                  )
                      ),
           substring('buy',
                      1 div not(/*[leasehold='Yes'
                                     and
                                       propertyTypes/propertyType = 'RESIDENTIAL'
                                      ]
                                  )
                      )
               )
```

This should give you an idea how to translate the whole conditional expression into a single XPath 1.0 expression.

**XSLT 1.0 - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
   "concat(
           substring('rent',
                      1 div boolean(/*[leasehold='Yes'
                                     and
                                       propertyTypes/propertyType = 'RESIDENTIAL'
                                      ]
                                  )
                      ),
           substring('buy',
                      1 div not(/*[leasehold='Yes'
                                     and
                                       propertyTypes/propertyType = 'RESIDENTIAL'
                                      ]
                                  )
                      )
               )
   "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document (above), the XPath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output:**

```
buy
```

**Do note**:

If you decide to replace the specific strings with other strings that have different lengths than the original, you simply replace these strings in the above XPath 1.0 expression and you don't have to worry about specifying any lengths.

Comment: Nice explanation. Is there a way to add the length of a node as a $cond?

Comment: @dan, As explained this isn't necessary. Thus, even if the length of a string is unknown or changes over time, this expression still expresses the desired conditional evaluation. Yes, it is possible to involve the lengths of the strings, but the expression that icludes them is very brittle and length-dependent

Answer (score 2):

Becker's method for your data is the following:

```
concat(substring('Rent',      1 div boolean(propertyTypes/propertyType ="RESIDENTIAL" and leasehold="Yes")),
       substring('Buy',       1 div boolean(propertyTypes/propertyType ="RESIDENTIAL" and leasehold="No")),
       substring('Leasehold', 1 div boolean(propertyTypes/propertyType!="RESIDENTIAL" and leasehold="Yes")),
       substring('Freehold',  1 div boolean(propertyTypes/propertyType!="RESIDENTIAL" and leasehold="No")))
```

Comment: choroba, You may be interested in a more generic XPath 1.0 expression, which doesn't need lengths to be specified (and modified whenever we want to use different strings as results).

Answer (score 1):

Spent all day today, but works for me this is for Xpath 1.0:

```
concat(
substring(properties/property[@name="Headline"], 1, string-length(properties/property[@name="Headline"]) * 1), 
substring(properties/property[@name="Name"], 1, not(number(string-length(properties/property[@name="Headline"]))) * string-length(properties/property[@name="Name"]))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (condition) 
then 
  if (condition) stmnt 
  else stmnt 
else 
  if (condition) stmnt 
  else stmnt
```