# check xslt:variable in a xslt:select

Tags: c#, xslt

Is there a way I can check my variable in the select attribute and call one of two user functions `TestFx` or `TestFx2`. Now I know I can use `xsl:if` or `xsl:choose`, but was just wondering if there was another way.

For example `select="$hasTextArea=true ? TestFx : TestFx2"`

```
<xsl:variable name="hasTextArea">true</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template name="break">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
    <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="user:TestFx($text)" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Rod, Yes, there is such a way and it isn't so difficult or tricky, after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT 1.0 does not have a ternary operator. Just use `<xsl:if>` or `<xsl:choose>` and spend your time on something more worthwhile than trying to find a clever hack. (You can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971067/is-there-an-if-then-else-statement-in-xpath), if you really must.)

XSLT 2.0 (i.e. XPath 2.0) has this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="
  if ($hasTextArea = 'true') 
    then user:TestFx($text) 
    else user:TestFx2($text)
" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can check my variable in the select attribute and
>   call one of two user functions `TestFx` or `TestFx2`. Now I know I can use
>   `xsl:if` or `xsl:choose`, but was just wondering if there was another way.

**Here is a complete demo how to do this. This illustrates the basic principle how to implement higher-order functions in XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 -- used in the [FXSL library for functional programming with XSLT](http://fxsl.sf.net)**.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:user="my:user" xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <my:functions>
   <my:F1/>
   <my:F2/>
 </my:functions>

 <xsl:variable name="vMyFuncs" select="document('')/*/my:functions/*"/>

 <xsl:param name="phasTextArea" select="true()"/>
 <xsl:param name="pText" select="'Some Text'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:variable name="vFunc" select=
      "$vMyFuncs[1][$phasTextArea] | $vMyFuncs[2][not($phasTextArea)]"/>

  <xsl:apply-templates select="$vFunc"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="my:F1">
  <xsl:value-of select="user:TestFx($pText)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="my:F2">
  <xsl:value-of select="user:TestFx2($pText)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <msxsl:script language = "c#"  implements-prefix = "user">
  public string TestFx(string text)
  {
    return "Text is: " + "'" +text + "'";
  }

  public string TestFx2(string text)
  {
    return string.Format("Text length is: {0}", text.Length);
  }
</msxsl:script>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted correct result (`user:TestFx()` called) is produced**:

```
Text is: 'Some Text'
```

**If we modify the code above by setting the `$phasTextArea` to `false()`, the result now shows that this time `user:TestFx2()` has been called**:

```
Text length is: 9
```

**And, as promised, the transformation has no explicit XSLT conditional instructions** (`xsl:choose` or `xsl:if`).

**Also, we don't count characters to do unnecessary tricks with `substring()`.**