# if xpath result is empty return "empty" string

Tags: xml, xpath

how to make `xpath` 1.0 behave like if value is empty - return string `"empty"`

if I have an XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<query systemEnvironmentCode="UAT">
    <trxid>107</trxid>
    <ladid/>
</query>
```

In case when `ladid` is empty I want it to return `"empty"` string, if it's not empty - return `ladid`'s value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to have the string `empty` instead of an empty sting as a result for empty elements the following XPath should do it:

```
concat(
    substring(string(/query/ladid), 1,
        number(string(/query/ladid) != '') * string-length(/query/ladid)),
    substring('empty', 1,
        number(string(/query/ladid) = '') * 5)
)
```

It is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/971665/948404.

Answer (score 0):

Use the path `string(/query/ladid)`.