# Xpath boolean OR (equivalent to Python's A | B: return A if non-empty, otherwise B)

Tags: python, xpath

Lets say I have html:

```html
<body>
  <div class="items">
    <span class="label">label1</span>
    <div class="value">value1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="items">
    <span class="label">label2</span>
    <div class="value">
      <a class="link">value2</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="items">
    <span class="label">label3</span>
    <div class="value">
      <a class="link">value3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="items">
    <span class="label">label4</span>
    <div class="value">value4</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Im trying to get text from `<a class="link">` if possible or from `<div class=value>`.

```py
for result in response.xpath("//div[@class='items']"):
    label = result.xpath(".//span[@class='label']//text()").extract_first()
    # here Im trying use or operation to get 
    # a text if possible or div text
    value = result.xpath(".//a[@class='link']//text()"
                         "|.//div[@class='value']//text()").get()
    print(label, value)
```

Results:

```
label1 value1
label2 
label3 
label4 value4
```

This code assign only text from `<div class='value'>` although `<a class='link'>` exist.

**What I need?**
I would like to xpath code return `a` text if possible in otherwise it should take `div` text.

Comment: Think of this like a set-union OR, not a boolean OR; just like if you run `{1,2} | {3}` in Python, you get `{1,2,3}` as a result.

Comment: Okay, is there an option to get the result that interests me?

Comment: Is it *possible*? Yes. Is it *easier than doing the logic in Python*? No. Honestly, what I recommend in practice is just running two separate XPath queries.

Comment: For the general approach demonstrating that it's possible, see [Is there an if-then-else statement in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971067/is-there-an-if-then-else-statement-in-xpath).

Comment: I need to seperate this logic. I do something like this `# value = result.xpath('''if(.//a[@class='link']/text())) then .//a[@class='link']/text()) else .//div[@class='value']/text()''').get()`, but in result i have only exception from xpath interpreter.

Comment: @magnus250 There is a much simpler and shorter XPath expression that selects the wanted text nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the xpath that you should use.

```
//div[@class='items'][2]//div[@class='value']/a|//div[@class='items'][2]//div[@class='value'][not(a)]
```

So replace this in your code.

```
value = result.xpath(".//div[@class='value']/a/text()|.//div[@class='value'][not(a)]/text()").get()
```

Comment: Try this and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hey, Your result returns only `<div class='value'>` text.

Comment: Sorry, I over looked the div with the same class name. Can you try with the updated answer.

Comment: Do you know answer of this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59515506/xpath-get-text-with-br

Answer (score 0):

> Im trying to get text from `<a class="link">` if possible or from `<div> class=value>`

**Here is a simple / short XPath 1.0 expression that selects exactly all the wanted text nodes**:

```
(//div[@class='value'] | //a[@class='link'])/text()
```

**XSLT 1.0 - based verification:**

This transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="(//div[@class='value'] | //a[@class='link'])/text()">
      <xsl:if test="not(position() = 1)">, </xsl:if>
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**evaluates the XPath expression and outputs each selected text-node using convenient delimiters**.

**The wanted result is produced**:

```
value1, value2, value3, value4
```